# Android 3 tabs/fragments and with different action item for each

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am developing an app which has 3 tabs/fragments. However I want to have different actionbar for each tab. How can I do that?

This is what I've tried so far:
**FragmentActivity**

```
// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = { "Settings", "Company", "Receipt" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.systemsettings_main);

    // Initialization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    //actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS); 


    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    /**
     * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
     * */
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
}


@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, android.app.FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.systemsettings_menu, menu);

    final MenuItem itemAdd;

    itemAdd = menu.findItem(R.id.save);


    itemAdd.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

            return true;
        }
    });

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

But this does not accomplish my requirements for it displays only the systemsettings_menu. Do you have any ideas how to do this? I would gladly appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "a different action bar"? Is it "different action items in the bar"?

Comment: @matiash yes that's it different items in the bar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each Fragment can declare its menu items separately, and the framework will build the action bar based on those. Instead of overriding the Activity's onCreateOptionsMenu(), you should:

- Make each fragment return true for [setHasOptionsMenu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setHasOptionsMenu%28boolean%29).
- Make each fragment add its menu items by overriding [Fragment.onCreateOptionsMenu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu,%20android.view.MenuInflater%29).
- Toggle [setMenuVisibility()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setMenuVisibility%28boolean%29) for each Fragment, as it's shown or hidden (i.e. when switching tabs).
- Implement [onOptionsItemSelected()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onOptionsItemSelected%28android.view.MenuItem%29) in each Fragment, to handle these actions.

That should be enough for your purposes.

For a good example, see https://www.grokkingandroid.com/adding-action-items-from-within-fragments/